# array in css for multiple ID's

Tags: css, arrays

Is this possible to make an array for CSS?

```
    <style>
    #info1, #info2, #info3, #info4 {
    display: none;
    }
    </style>
```

Let's say I have 20 hidden divs identified by id="info1", id="info2" 20 times. but I don't want to declare in my styles #info1, #info2, ... #info20. Can this be accomplished with an array or another method.

Comment: You can make a class `.NoShow{display: none;}`

Comment: If they're all going to share a style, then just give them a class.

Comment: How would a 20-item array be different from this? I have the impression that you've over-simplified the example.

Comment: FYI they can't share the same class or ID since I'll be using radio buttons and check boxes to toggle the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is option to use attribute selector:

```
[id^="info"] { /* gets all elements where id starting with info */
    display: none;
}
```

[Demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7dSH/1/)

You can find more about attribute selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: How does that translate to #info1, #info2 ... #info20?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is adding a class to those div

```
.noshow{
  display: none;
}
```

And if not possible, you can do  what @asku said in his answer

Answer (score 0):

What @Emilio Gort said is the right way to have a rule on multiple elements.

```
#Parent>.noshow{
    display:none;
}
```

You would be able to toggle the class using javascript to show or hide some elements.

But if you want to apply specific rules to elements which you partly know the name, without using a general rule tied to a specific class like stated above, use attribute selection like suggested by @aksu.

I personally prefer to use the class attribute, but you can use this on any attribute you want.

```
#Parent>*[class*="info"]{
    display:none;
}

<div id="Parent">
    <div class="some-info-1"></div><!-- hidden -->
    <div class="some-something-else-1"></div>
    <div class="some-info-2"></div><!-- hidden -->
    <div class="some-something-else-2"></div>
    <div class="some-info-3"></div><!-- hidden -->
    <div class="some-something-else-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I've read comments of the original post and now I understand why you needed the id attribute instead of the class. id attribute selection is the good option then.